# How do I make my new SSD my primary SSD and keep the old one as a secondary SSD?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, nvme

I bought an M.2 NVME SSD that I want to install as my primary/boot drive. I currently have a 2.5" SSD in my PC that has a lot of stuff on it. How can I make the NVME SSD my primary drive and make my 2.5" SSD my secondary drive? Do I still have to move and partition everything from the 2.5" onto the NVME? (The new SSD is 1TB larger than the 2.5")

P.S. I am still on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

> I bought an M.2 NVME SSD that I want to install as my primary/boot
> drive. I currently have a 2.5" SSD in my PC that has a lot of stuff on
> it. How can I make the NVME SSD my primary drive and make my 2.5" SSD
> my secondary drive?

I have done this myself.

The best way for me and with reasonably easy to follow steps (although not the only way) is to temporarily remove the old SSD drive and install the new drive.

Having only one drive in the system prevents Windows from thinking it needs two drives to start up.

Install Windows, set it up with Apps and data (which I assumed you backed up from the old drive).

Note: Installing Windows fresh takes a bit more time now, but I prefer this to cloning an older system and bringing errors over. This will pay off down the road.

When done, do a final restart to ensure all works.

Now put the old SSD back.  If a System Disk, format it to eliminate System Disk conflicts.

This has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically OS transfer operation, but it has dozen of hidden difficulties and drawbacks and try this only if you ready to lose all data and have about 3 spare days.
Asking for help of a person who already did that multiple times may be correct way to go.

Note that doing this on your own without any experience involves **risk of losing every file and previous OS**, that is including windows licence. If this is completely ok, than you can jump to step 3.

1. before even starting, there is risk that you system don't even support M.2 boot; sometimes complex things are necessary like BIOS update to enable it; googling you motherboard/laptop specifications usually helps
   also make sure that new M.2 have bigger or same capacity as your previous
   SSD, or advanced steps during transfer are almost guaranteed to be nessesary

for next steps it's optimal to have:

- clan 1GB+ USB drive for clonezilla
- clean external storage of any type (usb/hdd) for important files backup
- clean external hdd or around 1TB+ for full disk backup

2. do full backup of important/personal data on file level on separate disk/usb drive/internet storage like Google drive; make sure you CRC'ed most important folders and CRC matches on old drive and for backup files
   do not touch that usb for 3,4 steps
3. create bootable usb drive with rufus and clonezilla; load from it and do  full disk backup stored on separate hdd (better clean fresh backup hdd with lots of free space, like 1TB)
   if that's first time, optimal to use for this clean hdd without any data
   (backup will easily take half of day, but having such backup is good on it's own)
4. remove previous ssd, install new M.2 and do full disk restore from backup
   about 1/3 that will start directly without any problems
   about 1/3 that will never work after multiple days of google headache (less than 1/3 for newer laptops/motherboards)
   about 1/3 that will require advanced skills or soft to fix unusual errors

after ensuring that new M.2 is bootable, install back old SSD